# QGIS different scale levels in rule-based styling - in one rule

Tags: qgis, scale, rule-based

I have a layer with 4 roadclasses. For this layer I created a rule based symbolization, with 4 rules. In every rule I filter another roadclass and set a different symbolization and scale for this rule.
Now I want to create a fifth rule "road direction", which should show the road direction as an arrow. But this arrow should be visible in different scale levels, depending on the roadclass.

For example:
the roadclass 'A' the arrow should be visible from a scale 1:1500.000
the roadclass 'B' the arrow should be visible from a scale 1:400.000 
and so on

Can I set this in one rule? The aim is, that I can activate or deactivate the rule "road direction" with one click. I don´t want to create 4 different rules and the arrow should not be added to the 4 rules for the roadclasses.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to achieve? Right now I don't seem to get it. Would the arrow just be another rule? Or another layer? And why don't you display the roads with an arrow to begin with? Or you could add a second symbology to each or your rules.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I get it.
I set this filter rule to get the symbolization I want to create
[image]